# Data transfer from controller to view page

Tags: spring-mvc

**When I set a "message" attribute in `ModelMap`, it does not get displayed in the JSP.**  Instead of value of "message", string literal `${message}` is getting displayed in browser

UserHandler.java

[image: UserHandler.java]

hello.jsp
[image: hello.jsp]

spring-bean-config.xml
[image: spring-bean-config.xml]

web.xml
[image: web.xml]

Result page:  Here I expect to see `welcome` instead of `${message}`
[image: result page]

Comment: Can you ask clearly what is your question ?

Comment: the view page which is hello.jsp didn't display the value of message.  is there something wrong with with my controller?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is not in the controller, but in your view `hello.jsp`. What is happening is the view interpret  `${message}` as a literal text, not as the value of an attribute.

I've never work with jsp, but the following might do the trick for you.
In `hello.jsp` change the line: `${message}` for something like : `<c:out value="${message}" />`

Comment: it still displays the literal text ${message} on jsp page.

Comment: try with <c:out value="${model.message}" />

Answer (score 0):

user1442922,

Do you have the root root declarations on top of your web.xml and spring-bean-config.xml and just leave them off in your post for brevity? If you don't have them in your .xmls, try adding them, the one for web.xml should look something like:

```
<web-app
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
```